# Swap values and keys in a dictionary

Tags: python

I want to swap the years with the continent so that the continent is the primary key and the year the secondary one

```
    def get_most_infected_continents() -> List[Dict[str, any]]:
    """We calculate the most infected continents."""
    lst : List = list()
    string = ""
    for i in range(1990, 2021):
        dict2 = {}
        dict3 = {}
        dict1 = {}
        for dct in dataset:
            if dct[str(i)] == -1 or dct['continent'] == "Global":
                continue
            if dct["continent"] not in dict2 :
                dict2[dct["continent"]] = dct[str(i)]
            else:
                dict2[dct["continent"]] += dct[str(i)]
        maxim = 0
        for key in dict2:
            if int(dict2[key]) > maxim:
                maxim = dict2[key]
                string = key
        dict3[string] = maxim
        dict1[str(i)] = dict3
        lst.append(dict1)   
    return lst
get_most_infected_continents()
```

This is how the output kinda looks

```
[{'1990': {'Africa': 5736700}},
{'1991': {'Africa': 7026700}},
{'1992': {'Africa': 8423800}},
{'1990': {'Africa': 5736700}},
{'1991': {'Africa': 7026700}},
{'1992': {'Africa': 8423800}},....]
```

I would like to be

```
{'Africa': {'1990': 5736700}},...
```

The original dataset looks something like this but with all the countries:

```
country,continent,1990,1990_lower,1990_upper,1991,1991_lower,1991_upper,1992,1992_lower,1992_upper,1993,1993_lower,1993_upper,1994,1994_lower,1994_upper,1995,1995_lower,1995_upper,1996,1996_lower,1996_upper,1997,1997_lower,1997_upper,1998,1998_lower,1998_upper,1999,1999_lower,1999_upper,2000,2000_lower,2000_upper,2001,2001_lower,2001_upper,2002,2002_lower,2002_upper,2003,2003_lower,2003_upper,2004,2004_lower,2004_upper,2005,2005_lower,2005_upper,2006,2006_lower,2006_upper,2007,2007_lower,2007_upper,2008,2008_lower,2008_upper,2009,2009_lower,2009_upper,2010,2010_lower,2010_upper,2011,2011_lower,2011_upper,2012,2012_lower,2012_upper,2013,2013_lower,2013_upper,2014,2014_lower,2014_upper,2015,2015_lower,2015_upper,2016,2016_lower,2016_upper,2017,2017_lower,2017_upper,2018,2018_lower,2018_upper,2019,2019_lower,2019_upper,2020,2020_lower,2020_upper
Afghanistan,Asia,<500 ,<200 , <1000,<500 ,<200 , <1000,<500 ,<200 , <1000,<1000 ,<500 ,1100,<1000 ,<500 ,1300,<1000 ,<500 ,1600,<1000 ,<500 ,1900,1000,<500 ,2100,1200,<1000 ,2500,1300,<1000 ,3000,1500,<1000 ,3600,1800,<1000 ,4100,2000,1100,4800,2300,1300,5700,2600,1400,7000,2900,1500,7200,3200,1700,7900,3500,1800,8300,3800,2000,8900,4200,2100,9600,4600,2300, 11 000,5100,2500, 12 000,5600,2700, 14 000,6300,3100, 16 000,6900,3300, 18 000,7600,3600, 21 000,8400,3900, 24 000,9200,4100, 28 000,10 000 ,4300, 33 000,11 000 ,4500, 38 000,12 000 ,4700, 43 000
Albania,Europe,<100 ,<100 , <100,<100 ,<100 , <100,<100 ,<100 , <100,<100 ,<100 , <100,<100 ,<100 , <100,<100 ,<100 , <100,<100 ,<100 , <100,<100 ,<100 , <100,<100 ,<100 , <100,<100 ,<100 , <200,<100 ,<100 , <200,<200 ,<100 , <200,<200 ,<200 , <200,<200 ,<200 , <500,<500 ,<200 , <500,<500 ,<500 , <500,<500 ,<500 , <500,<500 ,<500 , <500,<500 ,<500 , <1000,<1000 ,<500 , <1000,<1000 ,<1000 , <1000,<1000 ,<1000 , <1000,<1000 ,<1000 , <1000,<1000 ,<1000 ,1000,1000,<1000 ,1100,1100,<1000 ,1200,1200,<1000 ,1300,1300,1100,1400,1300,1100,1500,1400,1200,1600,1400,1200,1700
.....
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Swap+values+and+keys+in+a+dictionary+python

Comment: could you by chance provide what the `dataset` variable represents? it seemingly is a dictionary from the csv file so could you show that one (like print it out or sth and then copy paste that?)? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Actually your code needs to be optimized, but replacing this line `lst.append(dict1)`

With this

```
lst.append({string:{str(i):maxim}})
```

Will do the job :)

Comment: Thanks so much it solved it

Comment: @breidi can you please still provide the dataset?

Comment: @breidi you are welcome..  
Don't forget to remover dict3[string] = maxim and dict1[str(i)] = dict3 because you no longer need them.

Comment: the dataset is a csv file on my computer but i can show a part of it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the dataset is:

```py
[{'1990': {'Africa': 5736700}},
 {'1991': {'Africa': 7026700}},
 {'1992': {'Africa': 8423800}},
 {'1990': {'Africa': 5736700}},
 {'1991': {'Africa': 7026700}},
 {'1992': {'Africa': 8423800}}]
```

Let's just look at one piece of that data:

```py
datum = {'1990': {'Africa': 5736700}}
```

We can get the year thusly:

```py
year = datum.keys()[0]
```

We can get the continent thusly:

```py
continent = datum.values()[0].keys()[0]
```

And we can get the actual relevant info thusly:

```py
info = datum.values()[0].values()[0]
```

Knowing these things, it's pretty easy to construct the output data format you're looking for:

```py
{continent: {year: info}}
```

We can put this together pretty straightforwardly in a loop. *Thanks to @Matliss for helping to improve this code by explicit conversion to `list`.*

```py
data = [{'1990': {'Africa': 5736700}},
 {'1991': {'Africa': 7026700}},
 {'1992': {'Africa': 8423800}},
 {'1990': {'Africa': 5736700}},
 {'1991': {'Africa': 7026700}},
 {'1992': {'Africa': 8423800}}]

output = []

for datum in data:
    top_level_keys = list(datum.keys())
    top_level_vals = list(datum.values())
    
    snd_level_hash = top_level_vals[0]
    snd_level_keys = list(snd_level_hash.keys())
    snd_level_vals = list(snd_level_hash.values())
    
    year      = top_level_keys[0]
    continent = snd_level_keys[0]
    info      = snd_level_vals[0]
    
    output.append({continent: {year: info}})
```

I'm sure this can be cleaned up with a clever combination of list and dictionary comprehensions, but this seems the most straightforward way of doing things.

Never forget that every "big" problem is just a bunch of small problems.

Comment: did you run the code? it throws multiple errors, if you want to use indexes then convert to list first (you need quite a lot of those)

Comment: Yes, I did. I didn't get any errors.

Comment: weird, because it was telling me: `TypeError: 'dict_keys' object is not subscriptable`, what version are you using?

Comment: yeah the original database is different than the one you are assuming, it begins with all the keys and then all the values come after

Comment: I am using Python 2.7.16 currently.

Comment: @Chris well that makes sense then, that version is deprecated btw, you shouldn't be really using it anyways, well on python 3 everything should be explicitly converted to `list`

Comment: Not on my usual machine. Going with what's available.

Comment: Edited to correct this in the final code sample.